# No connection warning shows up after I minimize and open the app again in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `observe_internet_connectivity` package to observe if my internet is off. So, I used it to open a bottom sheet to show that internet is not connected. But, whenever I minimize my app and open it again, the warning shows up and never goes out. How do I solve this? PS: This is happening when I am debugging the app.

Here is the code:

```
ValueNotifier<int> isConnectedToInternet=ValueNotifier(-1);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    firstCheck=-1;
    ScreenSize.init(context);
    return InternetConnectivityListener(
      connectivityListener: (BuildContext context, bool hasInternetAccess) {
        if (hasInternetAccess) {
          if(firstCheck!=-1) {
            showToast(
              'Connected to Internet',
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              textColor: Colors.white
            );
            isConnectedToInternet.value=1;
          }
          firstCheck=0;
        } else {
          isConnectedToInternet.value=2;
          firstCheck=0;
        }
      },
      child: MultiProvider(
        providers: [ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => MainProvider())],
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: myCustomTheme,
          scaffoldMessengerKey: scaffoldMessengerKey,
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
          initialRoute: MyRoute.splashScreen,
          onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Scaffold(
              bottomSheet: BottomSheet(
                onClosing: () {  },
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return ValueListenableBuilder(
                    valueListenable: isConnectedToInternet,
                    builder: (context, isConnected, child) {
                      if(isConnected==2) {
                        return const NoInternetConnectionWarning();
                      }
                      else {
                        return const SizedBox();
                      }
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
              body: StreamBuilder<bool>(.......
```

Also, can someone suggest me any improvements over this? Like, I want that contents of snackbar could be displayed on bottom sheet, for 3 seconds. Also, I want that when net is off, and it turn on again, only then it shows bottom sheet for connected.
Any suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution.

So, this is the output of the below-mentioned source code: [View](https://www.veed.io/view/09c50cf6-4978-47ac-b5d8-30597bc11bbd?sharingWidget=true&panel=share)

Source code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  StreamSubscription<bool>? subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    subscription = InternetConnectivity().observeInternetConnection.listen(
      (bool hasInternetAccess) {
        final String msg = hasInternetAccess ? "Connected!" : "Disconnected!";
        final SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(msg));
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> dispose() async {
    await subscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SizedBox(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```